# Image on publishing page does not display after I publish page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, publishing-page, 2016

I created a page layout based on "Page" type where I am showing three fields:

1. Title
2. Page Image
3. Page Content

I am logged in a System Account.

Let's say I am adding a new page. While I am adding a page I set its title, upload image and add content. I can see image being displayed on screen but page is not published yet. Now when I publish the page then image disappears.

The library where image is being uploaded is standard "PublishingImages" library where every one has access.

Similarly if I edit that page then in EDIT mode that image is displayed. If I SAVE page then it keep displaying. If I move to another page and then come back to this page then image disappears OR if I simply publish the page then image disappears.

So in short:

While adding or editing page upload image and it will display. You SAVE page (but not publish or check in) and image will continue to display. You navigate to another page and come back to this page OR simply publish the page and in both cases image disappears.

This is really crazy I don't know what's going on here. Can you please tell me what to do?

[image]

Comment: I removed "Page Image" field and added "Rollup Image" and problem is fixed. But I wonder why "Page Image" is behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Page Layouts, you can set the Field Controls
to show only in Edit Mode and not show in view mode.
Looks like your roll up image is set to show in view mode and for page image it was set with not to show in view mode. Please check the setting for edit mode settings for the Page Image field control.